# Can compile in C++17 but not in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a very simple code example.
I can compile it in C++17 but cannot in C++20. Why not?

```
struct S
{
    S(const S&) = delete;
    S( S&& ) = default;

    int k;
    int m;
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    S s1{10, 20, 30};
    return s1.m;
}
```

Comment: There is pretty much no legitimate use case for a type with a deleted copy construct and a defaulted move constructor. If the default move (ie: copy) is OK for the object on move, then the object is logically copyable.

Answer (score 5):

This is because of [P1008](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf), which changed the rule for what qualifies as an aggregate from

> no user-provided, explicit, or inherited constructors

to

> no user-declared or inherited constructors

Your constructors are user-declared but not user-provided (you declare them, so they're user-declared, but they're defaulted on their initial declaration, so you're not providing a definition for them). In C++17, `S` is an aggregate. But in C++20, it is not. Because of that, there is no aggregate initialization anymore, so `S{10, 20, 30}` can only invoke constructors - of which there is no viable one.

If you want this to keep working, you'll have to provide a constructor.

For more details on C++20 changes to aggregates, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53819762/2069064).